# How to write criteria query involving an object and another related object of different class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My controller method

```
@Override
        public List<SuggestedCompnayiesDTO> filterSuggestedCompanies(Long partnerId, Boolean isPharmacy) {
            CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<SuggestedCompnayies> query = builder.createQuery(SuggestedCompnayies.class);
            Root<SuggestedCompnayies> root = query.from(SuggestedCompnayies.class);
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (partnerId != null) {
    
                predicates.add(builder.equal(companyRepository.findById(root.get("partnerId"), partnerId));
            }
    
    //This line here causes the problem
    
            if (isHospital != null) {
    
                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("companyId").get("isHospital")), isHospital));
            }
            query.select(root).where(builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]))).distinct(true);
            List<SuggestedCompnayiesDTO> suggestedCompnayiesDTO = suggestedCompnayiesMapper.toDto(em.createQuery(query).getResultList());
            
            return suggestedCompnayiesDTO;
        }
    }
```

Here I have an object of class `SuggestedCompanies` and it contains a field of type `Company`.My query need to involve checking conditions on both these objects.Ie I need to return only `SuggestedCompany` objects whose `partnerId` matches with the input and its inner object company's `isPharmacy` attribute set to true.
I tried following piece of code

```
        predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("companyId").get("isHospital")), isHospital));
```

But I get the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Path<Object> to Long`
How can I solve this problem?

Update

Entity Classes

```
public class SuggestedCompnayies implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("suggestedByComapnies")
    private Partner suggestedBy;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("suggestedToComapnies")
    private Partner suggestedTo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("suggestedComapnies")
    private Company company;

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Partner getSuggestedBy() {
        return suggestedBy;
    }

    public SuggestedCompnayies suggestedBy(Partner partner) {
        this.suggestedBy = partner;
        return this;
    }

    public void setSuggestedBy(Partner partner) {
        this.suggestedBy = partner;
    }

    public Partner getSuggestedTo() {
        return suggestedTo;
    }

    public SuggestedCompnayies suggestedTo(Partner partner) {
        this.suggestedTo = partner;
        return this;
    }

    public void setSuggestedTo(Partner partner) {
        this.suggestedTo = partner;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public SuggestedCompnayies company(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
        return this;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof SuggestedCompnayies)) {
            return false;
        }
        return id != null && id.equals(((SuggestedCompnayies) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SuggestedCompnayies{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Company

```
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "location")
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "google_map_location")
    private String googleMapLocation;

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private String longitude;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private String latitude;

    @Column(name = "street_1")
    private String street1;

    @Column(name = "street_2")
    private String street2;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "zipcode")
    private Long zipcode;

    @Column(name = "contact_number")
    private Long contactNumber;

    @Column(name = "logo")
    private String logo;

    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;

    @Column(name = "is_pharmacy")
    private Boolean isPharmacy;

    @Column(name = "is_hospital")
    private Boolean isHospital;

    @Column(name = "is_laboratory")
    private Boolean isLaboratory;

    @Column(name = "is_distributor")
    private Boolean isDistributor;

    @Column(name = "is_group_pharmacy")
    private Boolean isGroupPharmacy;

    @Column(name = "created_by_id")
    private Long createdById;

    @Column(name = "updated_by_id")
    private Long updatedById;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Instant createdOn;

    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    private Instant updatedOn;

    @Column(name = "is_approved")
    private Boolean isApproved;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Boolean isActive;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<CompanySubscription> subscriptions = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<DocumentType> types = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Review> reviews = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Rating> ratings = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<WorkingHour> workingHours = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Gallery> galleries = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Company> parentCompanies = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<SuggestedCompnayies> suggestedComapnies = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("companies")
    private State state;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("parentCompanies")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "companies")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Partner> partners = new HashSet<>();

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Company name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public Company email(String email) {
        this.email = email;
        return this;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public Company location(String location) {
        this.location = location;
        return this;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getGoogleMapLocation() {
        return googleMapLocation;
    }

    public Company googleMapLocation(String googleMapLocation) {
        this.googleMapLocation = googleMapLocation;
        return this;
    }

    public void setGoogleMapLocation(String googleMapLocation) {
        this.googleMapLocation = googleMapLocation;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public Company longitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        return this;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public Company latitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        return this;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getStreet1() {
        return street1;
    }

    public Company street1(String street1) {
        this.street1 = street1;
        return this;
    }

    public void setStreet1(String street1) {
        this.street1 = street1;
    }

    public String getStreet2() {
        return street2;
    }

    public Company street2(String street2) {
        this.street2 = street2;
        return this;
    }

    public void setStreet2(String street2) {
        this.street2 = street2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public Company city(String city) {
        this.city = city;
        return this;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Long getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }

    public Company zipcode(Long zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        return this;
    }

    public void setZipcode(Long zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public Long getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public Company contactNumber(Long contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        return this;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(Long contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    public String getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    public Company logo(String logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
        return this;
    }

    public void setLogo(String logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public Company image(String image) {
        this.image = image;
        return this;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Boolean isIsPharmacy() {
        return isPharmacy;
    }

    public Company isPharmacy(Boolean isPharmacy) {
        this.isPharmacy = isPharmacy;
        return this;
    }

    public void setIsPharmacy(Boolean isPharmacy) {
        this.isPharmacy = isPharmacy;
    }

    public Boolean isIsHospital() {
        return isHospital;
    }

    public Company isHospital(Boolean isHospital) {
        this.isHospital = isHospital;
        return this;
    }

    public void setIsHospital(Boolean isHospital) {
        this.isHospital = isHospital;
    }

    public Boolean isIsLaboratory() {
        return isLaboratory;
    }

    public Company isLaboratory(Boolean isLaboratory) {
        this.isLaboratory = isLaboratory;
        return this;
    }

    public void setIsLaboratory(Boolean isLaboratory) {
        this.isLaboratory = isLaboratory;
    }

    public Boolean isIsDistributor() {
        return isDistributor;
    }

    public Company isDistributor(Boolean isDistributor) {
        this.isDistributor = isDistributor;
        return this;
    }

    public void setIsDistributor(Boolean isDistributor) {
        this.isDistributor = isDistributor;
    }

    public Boolean isIsGroupPharmacy() {
        return isGroupPharmacy;
    }

    public Company isGroupPharmacy(Boolean isGroupPharmacy) {
        this.isGroupPharmacy = isGroupPharmacy;
        return this;
    }

    public void setIsGroupPharmacy(Boolean isGroupPharmacy) {
        this.isGroupPharmacy = isGroupPharmacy;
    }

    public Long getCreatedById() {
        return createdById;
    }

    public Company createdById(Long createdById) {
        this.createdById = createdById;
        return this;
    }

    public void setCreatedById(Long createdById) {
        this.createdById = createdById;
    }

    public Long getUpdatedById() {
        return updatedById;
    }

    public Company updatedById(Long updatedById) {
        this.updatedById = updatedById;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUpdatedById(Long updatedById) {
        this.updatedById = updatedById;
    }

    public Instant getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public Company createdOn(Instant createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
        return this;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Instant createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public Instant getUpdatedOn() {
        return updatedOn;
    }

    public Company updatedOn(Instant updatedOn) {
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUpdatedOn(Instant updatedOn) {
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
    }

    public Boolean isIsApproved() {
        return isApproved;
    }

    public Company isApproved(Boolean isApproved) {
        this.isApproved = isApproved;
        return this;
    }

    public void setIsApproved(Boolean isApproved) {
        this.isApproved = isApproved;
    }

    public Boolean isIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public Company isActive(Boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
        return this;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public Company userId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public Company username(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public Company password(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        return this;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<CompanySubscription> getSubscriptions() {
        return subscriptions;
    }

    public Company subscriptions(Set<CompanySubscription> companySubscriptions) {
        this.subscriptions = companySubscriptions;
        return this;
    }

    public Company addSubscription(CompanySubscription companySubscription) {
        this.subscriptions.add(companySubscription);
        companySubscription.setCompany(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Company removeSubscription(CompanySubscription companySubscription) {
        this.subscriptions.remove(companySubscription);
        companySubscription.setCompany(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setSubscriptions(Set<CompanySubscription> companySubscriptions) {
        this.subscriptions = companySubscriptions;
    }

    public Set<DocumentType> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    public Company types(Set<DocumentType> documentTypes) {
        this.types = documentTypes;
        return this;
    }

    public Company addTypes(DocumentType documentType) {
        this.types.add(documentType);
        documentType.setCompany(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Company removeTypes(DocumentType documentType) {
        this.types.remove(documentType);
        documentType.setCompany(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setTypes(Set<DocumentType> documentTypes) {
        this.types = documentTypes;
    }

    public Set<Review> getReviews() {
        return reviews;
    }

    public Company reviews(Set<Review> reviews) {
        this.reviews = reviews;
        return this;
    }

    public Company addReviews(Review review) {
        this.reviews.add(review);
        review.setCompany(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Company removeReviews(Review review) {
        this.reviews.remove(review);
        review.setCompany(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setReviews(Set<Review> reviews) {
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }

    public Set<Rating> getRatings() {
        return ratings;
    }

    public Company ratings(Set<Rating> ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
        return this;
    }

    public Company addRatings(Rating rating) {
        this.ratings.add(rating);
        rating.setCompany(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Company removeRatings(Rating rating) {
        this.ratings.remove(rating);
        rating.setCompany(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setRatings(Set<Rating> ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }

    public Set<WorkingHour> getWorkingHours() {
        return workingHours;
    }

    public Company workingHours(Set<WorkingHour> workingHours) {
        this.workingHours = workingHours;
        return this;
    }

    public Company addWorkingHours(WorkingHour workingHour) {
        this.workingHours.add(workingHour);
        workingHour.setCompany(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Company removeWorkingHours(WorkingHour workingHour) {
        this.workingHours.remove(workingHour);
        workingHour.setCompany(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setWorkingHours(Set<WorkingHour> workingHours) {
        this.workingHours = workingHours;
    }

    public Set<Gallery> getGalleries() {
        return galleries;
    }

    public Company galleries(Set<Gallery> galleries) {
        this.galleries = galleries;
        return this;
    }

    public Company addGallery(Gallery gallery) {
        this.galleries.add(gallery);
        gallery.setCompany(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Company removeGallery(Gallery gallery) {
        this.galleries.remove(gallery);
        gallery.setCompany(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setGalleries(Set<Gallery> galleries) {
        this.galleries = galleries;
    }

    public Set<Company> getParentCompanies() {
        return parentCompanies;
    }

    public Company parentCompanies(Set<Company> companies) {
        this.parentCompanies = companies;
        return this;
    }

    public Company addParentCompany(Company company) {
        this.parentCompanies.add(company);
        company.setCompany(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Company removeParentCompany(Company company) {
        this.parentCompanies.remove(company);
        company.setCompany(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setParentCompanies(Set<Company> companies) {
        this.parentCompanies = companies;
    }

    public Set<SuggestedCompnayies> getSuggestedComapnies() {
        return suggestedComapnies;
    }

    public Company suggestedComapnies(Set<SuggestedCompnayies> suggestedCompnayies) {
        this.suggestedComapnies = suggestedCompnayies;
        return this;
    }

    public Company addSuggestedComapnies(SuggestedCompnayies suggestedCompnayies) {
        this.suggestedComapnies.add(suggestedCompnayies);
        suggestedCompnayies.setCompany(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Company removeSuggestedComapnies(SuggestedCompnayies suggestedCompnayies) {
        this.suggestedComapnies.remove(suggestedCompnayies);
        suggestedCompnayies.setCompany(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setSuggestedComapnies(Set<SuggestedCompnayies> suggestedCompnayies) {
        this.suggestedComapnies = suggestedCompnayies;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public Company state(State state) {
        this.state = state;
        return this;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public Company company(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
        return this;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public Set<Partner> getPartners() {
        return partners;
    }

    public Company partners(Set<Partner> partners) {
        this.partners = partners;
        return this;
    }

    public Company addPartners(Partner partner) {
        this.partners.add(partner);
        partner.getCompanies().add(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Company removePartners(Partner partner) {
        this.partners.remove(partner);
        partner.getCompanies().remove(this);
        return this;
    }

    public void setPartners(Set<Partner> partners) {
        this.partners = partners;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Company)) {
            return false;
        }
        return id != null && id.equals(((Company) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
            ", email='" + getEmail() + "'" +
            ", location='" + getLocation() + "'" +
            ", googleMapLocation='" + getGoogleMapLocation() + "'" +
            ", longitude='" + getLongitude() + "'" +
            ", latitude='" + getLatitude() + "'" +
            ", street1='" + getStreet1() + "'" +
            ", street2='" + getStreet2() + "'" +
            ", city='" + getCity() + "'" +
            ", zipcode=" + getZipcode() +
            ", contactNumber=" + getContactNumber() +
            ", logo='" + getLogo() + "'" +
            ", image='" + getImage() + "'" +
            ", isPharmacy='" + isIsPharmacy() + "'" +
            ", isHospital='" + isIsHospital() + "'" +
            ", isLaboratory='" + isIsLaboratory() + "'" +
            ", isDistributor='" + isIsDistributor() + "'" +
            ", isGroupPharmacy='" + isIsGroupPharmacy() + "'" +
            ", createdById=" + getCreatedById() +
            ", updatedById=" + getUpdatedById() +
            ", createdOn='" + getCreatedOn() + "'" +
            ", updatedOn='" + getUpdatedOn() + "'" +
            ", isApproved='" + isIsApproved() + "'" +
            ", isActive='" + isIsActive() + "'" +
            ", userId=" + getUserId() +
            ", username='" + getUsername() + "'" +
            ", password='" + getPassword() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Company entity also, you should post minimal code to reproduce your problem

Comment: Currently I am not seeing `partnerId` in `SuggestedCompnayies` entity may be missing. I added solutions use condition for the column in both related entity and own entity

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks Actually I have nothing to check on SuggestedCompanyies entity. I need to check partnerId of its field parnter and isHospital on its field company

Comment: Ok then follow the same as `isHospital`. see the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Join related entity first means join with `Company` first and then add as a condition on its property

```
Join<SuggestedCompnayies, Company> company = root.join("company");
predicates.add(builder.equal(company.get("isHospital"), isHospital));
```

And for the entity's property suppose `partnerId` is property then you can do this way

```
predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("partnerId"), partnerId));
```

Comment: what does this parameter company passed to root.join means? root.join("company") , I mean its not a variable,is that a string of any significance?

Comment: It's is the related entity field name(`private Company company;`) of `SuggestedCompnayies` class

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have missed the bracket, try changing it to:

```
predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("companyId")).get("isHospital"), isHospital));
```

Comment: `companyRepository.findById(root.get("companyId"))` this causes error